# При заданной в настройках PFV4 положительной полярности сигнала (TRIG POS) запись начинается даже когда на вход камеры подается TRIG NEG

Tags: камера

При заданной в настройках программы PFV4 положительной полярности сигнала (TRIG POS, вход INPUT 2) запись начинается в двух случаях:

1. когда на вход (INPUT 2) камер Photron Nova S12 и S16 (серия S) подаётся напряжение, соответствующее верхнему уровню (5V).
2. когда на вход (INPUT 2) камер Photron Nova S12 и S16 (серия S) подаётся напряжение, соответствующее нижнему уровню (0V).

При заданной в настройках программы PFV4 отрицательной полярности сигнала (TRIG NEG, вход INPUT 2) всё правильно: запись начинается когда на вход (INPUT 2) камер Photron Nova S12 и S16 (серия S) подаётся напряжение, соответствующее нижнему уровню (0V).

Надо чтобы при заданной в настройках программы PFV4 положительной полярности сигнала (TRIG POS, вход INPUT 2) запись начиналась только когда на вход (INPUT 2) камер Photron Nova S12 и S16 (серия S) подаётся напряжение, соответствующее верхнему уровню (5V).

К входу INPUT 2 подключен кабель TRIG SW IN. Напряжение подаётся нажатием на переключатель (ON/OFF) с другого АРМа. ON - это 5V. OFF - это 0V.